# python omniCV fisheye camera

Tags: python, opencv

I want the result of step2 image
but my result is like this

https://kaustubh-sadekar.github.io/OmniCV-Lib/ParamsGUI.html

There is an step 2 image in the link

[failed result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dqzPx.png)

[original image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9ujjz.jpg)

this is the code i used
Please help me to print successfully
I need to store the coordinates properly

RADIUS,aperture,delx,dely Save to fisheyeParams.txt file

```
import cv2
import numpy as np
from omnicv import fisheyeImgConv

def nothing(x):
    pass


WINDOW_NAME = "image"
Image_Path = './input/fisheye.png'

RADIUS = None

# Example of using the converter class
frame = cv2.imread(Image_Path)
frame = cv2.resize(frame, (800,800))
cv2.namedWindow(WINDOW_NAME, cv2.WINDOW_NORMAL)
cv2.resizeWindow(WINDOW_NAME, 800, 800)
N = 2 * max(frame.shape)
cv2.createTrackbar("radius", WINDOW_NAME, 0, N, nothing)
cv2.createTrackbar("Cx", WINDOW_NAME, N // 2, N, nothing)
cv2.createTrackbar("Cy", WINDOW_NAME, N // 2, N, nothing)

while True:
    if True:
        frame = cv2.imread(Image_Path)
        radius = cv2.getTrackbarPos("radius", WINDOW_NAME)
        Cx = cv2.getTrackbarPos("Cx", WINDOW_NAME)
        Cy = cv2.getTrackbarPos("Cy", WINDOW_NAME)
        frame = cv2.circle(frame, (Cx, Cy), radius, (0, 200, 0), 2)
        cv2.imshow(WINDOW_NAME, frame)
        if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == 27:
            RADIUS = radius
            cv2.destroyAllWindows()
            break

WINDOW_NAME = "set aperture"

cv2.namedWindow(WINDOW_NAME, cv2.WINDOW_NORMAL)
cv2.resizeWindow(WINDOW_NAME, 1200, 600)
cv2.createTrackbar("aperture", WINDOW_NAME, 0, 1000, nothing)
cv2.createTrackbar("del Cx", WINDOW_NAME, 500, 1000, nothing)
cv2.createTrackbar("del Cy", WINDOW_NAME, 500, 1000, nothing)

# Example of using the converter class

frame = cv2.imread(Image_Path)

frame = cv2.circle(frame, (frame.shape[1] // 2, frame.shape[0] // 2), 4, (255, 255, 255), -1)
frame = cv2.circle(frame, (frame.shape[1] // 2, frame.shape[0] // 2), 2, (0, 0, 0), -1)

outShape = [400,800]
inShape = frame.shape[:2]

mapper = fisheyeImgConv()
mapper.fisheye2equirect(frame, outShape, edit_mode=True)

while True:
    if True:
        aperture = cv2.getTrackbarPos("aperture", WINDOW_NAME)
        delx = cv2.getTrackbarPos("del Cx", WINDOW_NAME) - 500
        dely = cv2.getTrackbarPos("del Cy", WINDOW_NAME) - 500
        frame2 = mapper.fisheye2equirect(
            frame,
            outShape,
            aperture=aperture,
            delx=delx,
            dely=dely,
            radius=RADIUS,
            edit_mode=True)
        cv2.imshow("image3", frame2)

        frame2 = cv2.line(
            frame2,
            (int(frame2.shape[1] * 0.25), 0),
            (int(frame2.shape[1] * 0.25), int(frame2.shape[0])),
            (0, 180, 0),
            1,
        )
        frame2 = cv2.line(
            frame2,
            (int(frame2.shape[1] * 0.75), 0),
            (int(frame2.shape[1] * 0.75), int(frame2.shape[0])),
            (0, 180, 0),
            1,
        )
        frame2 = cv2.line(
            frame2,
            (0, int(frame2.shape[0] * 0.5)),
            (int(frame2.shape[1]), int(frame2.shape[0] * 0.5)),
            (0, 180, 0),
            1,
        )
        frame2 = cv2.line(
            frame2,
            (int(frame2.shape[1] * 0.5), 0),
            (int(frame2.shape[1] * 0.5), int(frame2.shape[0])),
            (0, 180, 0),
            1,
        )
        cv2.imshow(WINDOW_NAME, frame2)
        if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == 27:
            print("aperture : ", aperture)
            print("delx : ", delx)
            print("dely : ", dely)
            f = open("./input/fisheyeParams.txt", "w+")
            f.write(str(RADIUS) + "\n")
            f.write(str(aperture) + "\n")
            f.write(str(delx) + "\n")
            f.write(str(dely) + "\n")
            f.close()
            break
        frame2[:, :, :] = 0
        # cv2.imshow("image", frame2)
```

Comment: Is using any webcams?

Comment: The goal is to run it as an ip camera. But that's not the problem The example is a png file.

Answer (score 0):

There is a problem with omnicv.py that I discovered. I tested with the example code for equirectangular to perspective conversion from https://kaustubh-sadekar.github.io/OmniCV-Lib/Equirectangular-to-perspective.html. The conversion failed, so the 'np.float32' in Omnicv.py was flagged as error, but after changing 'np.bool' to 'bool' the 'np.float32' error disappeared and the code then worked.